# Remote db2 server connection to R studio

Tags: r, jdbc, db2, ibm-mobilefirst, iseries-navigator

I do connect DB2 using `i-Series` or `AQT` for running query. Now I want to get the data into R. The Db2 I'm trying to connect is on i5/OS version 7 release 2. 
I'm following the below steps in R (as I got it through some forum)

```
library(RJDBC)

### Connection configuration
dsn_driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
dsn_database = "MY_Bch"         # e.g. "BLUDB"
dsn_hostname = "Apsi0012"         # e.g.: "awh-yp-small03.services.dal.bluemix.net"
dsn_port = "50000"                # e.g. "50000" 
dsn_protocol = "TCPIP"            # i.e. "TCPIP"
dsn_uid = "<user-id>"        
dsn_pwd = "<Enter Password>"
```

Now when I run `jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "/usr/local/lib/db2jcc4.jar")`
I'm getting the error:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

The JDBC is not installed in my local. Am I following the right way to connect iSeries DB2 - please help.

Answer (score 0):

For an iSeries,  you should be using the JTOpen driver http://jt400.sourceforge.net